# Не получается QPixmap правильно отобразить в QLabel

Tags: c++, qt

Пытался в QLabel положить нарисованную картинку, но картинка оказалась очень большая, а Qt её не умеет сжимать.

Вот первый пример:

```
QPixmap pix; // картинка "гранулировки" ручки
pix.load("Kartinka.png");
ui->label_hand->setPixmap(pix);
ui->label_hand->setScaledContents(true);
```

Вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом решил сжать картинку, нашёл код в интернете :

```
QPixmap p; // load pixmap
p.load("Kartinka.png");

// get label dimensions
int w = ui->label_hand->width();
int h = ui->label_hand->height();

// set a scaled pixmap to a w x h window keeping its aspect ratio
ui->label_hand->setPixmap(p.scaled(w,h,Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
ui->label_hand->repaint();
```

Вот результат :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Как правильно сделать я тоже особо не знаю ибо по началу на десять позиций я сделал 10 кулейблов но они все равно не сходятся с позициями куслайдера.

Может быль лучше всего такой элемент как "рычаг управления на десять позиций" лучше всего на рисовать в опенгл ????

Но не уверен получиться за пару дней "намахать" сию ручку.

Comment: если вызовы `int w = ui->label_hand->width();` происходят в конструкторе виджета без предварительной установки фиксированного размера (setFixedSize()), т.е. до вызова show(), то лейбл будет иметь непредсказуемый размер, т.к. qt еще не отрисовал виджет, не просчитал лэйауты и лейбл еще не в курсе какой же у него размер. 
Если вы хотите чтобы картинка вписывалась в лейбл (т.е. чтобы лейбл не растягивался до размера картинки), то ваш второй вариант следует поместить в метод типа showEvent

Comment: @goldstar_labs а как это сделать я не понимаю, как это оформить в коде

Comment: @timob256, попробуйте зафиксировать размер label, например: `ui->label_hand->setFixedSize(400, 400);`

Comment: @gil9red спасибо сработало , но все равно той цели которую я ставил я так и не добился, цель была что бы куслайдер и картинка совпадала с рисочками куслайдера но у вы не вышло (((

Comment: @timob256, если вам надо чтобы картинка совпадала со ослайдером, то надо для начала перерисовать картинку, да и вообще это метод весьма так себе, картинки вместо интерфейса - это плохо

Comment: может посмотрите в сторону стилей? http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qslider

Comment: Если вам необходимо, чтобы были подписаны деления слайдера, то это можно сделать любым из предложенных здесь способов: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661877/qt-slider-widget-with-tick-text-labels , т.е. или формировать самому дополнительные лейблы или просто доработать базовый QSlider, чтобы он отображал

Comment: @goldstar_labs  спасибо особенно за ссылку с вопросом, я бы не смог его найти. (обязательно постараюсь его реализовать и тут отписаться о результате)